# Raspberry Pi not connecting to Wi-Fi (OctoPi)

Tags: wifi, pi-3

I have a Raspberry Pi that I plan to use to run OctoPrint (for a 3D printer) and I need to connect it to Wi-Fi. Any time I run `ifup wlan0`, I get:

```
wpa_supplicant:/sbin/woa_supplicant daemon failed to start
run-parts: /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/woasupplicant exited with return code 1
failed to bring up wlan0
```

My `wpa_supplicant.conf` is:

```
country=US
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
network={
ssid="theaternet"
psk="network123"
proto=RSN
key_mgmt=WPA2-PSK
pairwise=CCMP
auth_alg=OPEN
}
```

And the network/interfaces:

```
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-ssid "theaternet"
wpa-psk "network123"`
```

Comment: I don't know OctoPrint, or what OS you are running this on, but the `network/interfaces` you have listed is nonsense in any system. Provide more info of exactly you are running.

Comment: OctoPi IS a Os, it's for connecting to a 3d printer

Comment: Why are you using supplicant?  Are you trying to connect to multiple WiFi networks?

Comment: Explain your question, do you mean why not use the wifi from the OctoPi ROM or why not use interface?

Answer (score 1):

This is what is required to connect:

```
iface wlan0-octopi inet dhcp  # -- NOTE: "dhcp"
wpa-ssid "put SSID here"
wpa-psk "put password here"
```

This,

```
iface wlan0-octopi inet manual  # -- NOTE "manual"
```

in the Octopi docs is an error and should be corrected there.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using a WPA secured WiFi network, so you should have this section uncommented in your octopi-network.txt file:

### WPA/WPA2 secured

```
iface wlan0-octopi inet manual
wpa-ssid "put SSID here"
wpa-psk "put password here"
```

Comment: That file doesn't work properly, I ended up just setting it up like a normal raspian based system

Answer (score 0):

If you're running OctoPi, you should be adjusting the WiFi by making changes to `/octopi-network.txt`, as mentioned by others.

What happens when OctoPi receives an update, and everything breaks because you've changed how things work at the core?  It's going to be a lot harder to troubleshoot those issues.

After you return to true OctoPrint, or for others with a similar issue, try connecting over Ethernet and taking a look at the output of the service that controls your WiFi connection:

```
sudo journalctl -u ifup@wlan0.service
```

Additionally, utilize this service to start or stop your connection, not `ifup`:

```
systemctl stop ifup@wlan0.service # Disconnect WiFi
systemctl start ifup@wlan0.service # Connect WiFi
```